# Adding React-Window to Material-UI Enhanced Table: type is invalid -- expected a string or a class/function but got: array

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, windowing, react-window

I'm trying to add the windowing feature (from react-table virtualized-rows https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/virtualized-rows?file=/src/App.js:2175-2192)

to the Material-UI Enhanced Table (because I need the table of my application to be editable, with actions, filters, pagination..) from https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/material-UI-enhanced-table

both codes come from the official examples of react-table https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/5f67349a211c664dbc2eeaa9973c4d20f4e7e843/docs/examples/ui.md

Basically I started from the code of Material-UI Enhanced Table example  and I added the FixedSizeList tag with its attributes and also the variable totalColumnsWidth taken from useTable()

From Chrome console I'm getting the error:

**react.development.js:315 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: array.
Check the render method of `List`.
in List (at App.js:134)
react-dom.development.js:23965 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
Check the render method of `List`.**

What am I doing wrong?

```
 <FixedSizeList
            height={400}
            itemCount={10} 
            itemSize={35}
            width={totalColumnsWidth}
          >
   .....the table....
</FixedSizeList>
```

The current code is:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {
  useTable,
  usePagination
} from "react-table";

import {
  FixedSizeList,
  FixedSizeGrid
} from "react-window";

import makeData from "./makeData";

const Styles = styled.div `
  padding: 1rem;

  table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;

    tr {
      :last-child {
        td {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }

    th,
    td {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      border-right: 1px solid black;

      :last-child {
        border-right: 0;
      }

      input {
        font-size: 1rem;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        border: 0;
      }
    }
  }

  .pagination {
    padding: 0.5rem;
  }
`;

// Create an editable cell renderer
const EditableCell = ({
  value: initialValue,
  row: {
    index
  },
  column: {
    id
  },
  updateMyData, // This is a custom function that we supplied to our table instance
}) => {
  // We need to keep and update the state of the cell normally
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  // We'll only update the external data when the input is blurred
  const onBlur = () => {
    updateMyData(index, id, value);
  };

  // If the initialValue is changed external, sync it up with our state
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setValue(initialValue);
  }, [initialValue]);

  return <input value = {
    value
  }
  onChange = {
    onChange
  }
  onBlur = {
    onBlur
  }
  />;
};

// Set our editable cell renderer as the default Cell renderer
const defaultColumn = {
  Cell: EditableCell,
};

// Be sure to pass our updateMyData and the skipPageReset option
function Table({
  columns,
  data,
  updateMyData,
  skipPageReset
}) {
  // For this example, we're using pagination to illustrate how to stop
  // the current page from resetting when our data changes
  // Otherwise, nothing is different here.
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    prepareRow,
    totalColumnsWidth,
    page,
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageOptions,
    pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    setPageSize,
    state: {
      pageIndex,
      pageSize
    },
  } = useTable({
      columns,
      data,
      defaultColumn,
      // use the skipPageReset option to disable page resetting temporarily
      autoResetPage: !skipPageReset,

      // updateMyData isn't part of the API, but
      // anything we put into these options will
      // automatically be available on the instance.
      // That way we can call this function from our
      // cell renderer!
      updateMyData,
    },
    usePagination
  );

  // Render the UI for your table
  return ( <
    div >
    <
    table { ...getTableProps()
    } >
    <
    thead > {
      headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => ( <
        tr { ...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()
        } > {
          headerGroup.headers.map((column) => ( <
            th { ...column.getHeaderProps()
            } > {
              column.render("Header")
            } < /th>
          ))
        } <
        /tr>
      ))
    } <
    /thead> <
    tbody { ...getTableBodyProps()
    } >
    <
    FixedSizeList height = {
      400
    }
    itemCount = {
      10
    } //test before was {rows.length}
    itemSize = {
      35
    }
    width = {
      totalColumnsWidth
    } >
    {
      page.map((row, i) => {
        prepareRow(row);
        return ( <
          tr { ...row.getRowProps()
          } > {
            row.cells.map((cell) => {
              return ( <
                td { ...cell.getCellProps()
                } > {
                  cell.render("Cell")
                } < /td>
              );
            })
          } <
          /tr>
        );
      })
    } <
    /FixedSizeList> <
    /tbody> <
    /table> <
    div className = "pagination" >
    <
    button onClick = {
      () => gotoPage(0)
    }
    disabled = {!canPreviousPage
    } > {
      "<<"
    } <
    /button>{" "} <
    button onClick = {
      () => previousPage()
    }
    disabled = {!canPreviousPage
    } > {
      "<"
    } <
    /button>{" "} <
    button onClick = {
      () => nextPage()
    }
    disabled = {!canNextPage
    } > {
      ">"
    } <
    /button>{" "} <
    button onClick = {
      () => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)
    }
    disabled = {!canNextPage
    } > {
      ">>"
    } <
    /button>{" "} <
    span >
    Page {
      " "
    } <
    strong > {
      pageIndex + 1
    } of {
      pageOptions.length
    } <
    /strong>{" "} <
    /span> <
    span >
    |
    Go to page: {
      " "
    } <
    input type = "number"
    defaultValue = {
      pageIndex + 1
    }
    onChange = {
      (e) => {
        const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0;
        gotoPage(page);
      }
    }
    style = {
      {
        width: "100px"
      }
    }
    /> <
    /span>{" "} <
    select value = {
      pageSize
    }
    onChange = {
      (e) => {
        setPageSize(Number(e.target.value));
      }
    } >
    {
      [10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map((pageSize) => ( <
        option key = {
          pageSize
        }
        value = {
          pageSize
        } >
        Show {
          pageSize
        } <
        /option>
      ))
    } <
    /select> <
    /div> <
    /div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [{
        Header: "Name",
        columns: [{
            Header: "First Name",
            accessor: "firstName",
          },
          {
            Header: "Last Name",
            accessor: "lastName",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        Header: "Info",
        columns: [{
            Header: "Age",
            accessor: "age",
          },
          {
            Header: "Visits",
            accessor: "visits",
          },
          {
            Header: "Status",
            accessor: "status",
          },
          {
            Header: "Profile Progress",
            accessor: "progress",
          },
        ],
      },
    ], []
  );

  const [data, setData] = React.useState(() => makeData(20));
  const [originalData] = React.useState(data);
  const [skipPageReset, setSkipPageReset] = React.useState(false);

  // We need to keep the table from resetting the pageIndex when we
  // Update data. So we can keep track of that flag with a ref.

  // When our cell renderer calls updateMyData, we'll use
  // the rowIndex, columnId and new value to update the
  // original data
  const updateMyData = (rowIndex, columnId, value) => {
    // We also turn on the flag to not reset the page
    setSkipPageReset(true);
    setData((old) =>
      old.map((row, index) => {
        if (index === rowIndex) {
          return {
            ...old[rowIndex],
            [columnId]: value,
          };
        }
        return row;
      })
    );
  };

  // After data chagnes, we turn the flag back off
  // so that if data actually changes when we're not
  // editing it, the page is reset
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setSkipPageReset(false);
  }, [data]);

  // Let's add a data resetter/randomizer to help
  // illustrate that flow...
  const resetData = () => setData(originalData);

  return ( <
    Styles >
    <
    button onClick = {
      resetData
    } > Reset Data < /button> <
    Table columns = {
      columns
    }
    data = {
      data
    }
    updateMyData = {
      updateMyData
    }
    skipPageReset = {
      skipPageReset
    }
    /> <
    /Styles>
  );
}

export default App;
img {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #e3f2fd;
}

.fa.fa-edit {
  color: #18a2b9;
}

.list-group-item.delete:hover {
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  background-color: pink;
}

.list-group-item.update:hover {
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

.list-group-item.board:hover {
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

.fa.fa-minus-circle {
  color: red;
}

.landing {
  position: relative;
  /* background: url("../img/showcase.jpg") no-repeat; */
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: -24px;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

.landing-inner {
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.dark-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.card-form {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.latest-profiles-img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.form-control::placeholder {
  color: #bbb !important;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tag above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build`.
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things are going on here. First, the react-window components only accept a function/functional components as a child.

On a basic level you would have to move the stuff between the `FixedSizeList` tags into a function. So, something like:

```
// add useCallback here to prevent unnecessary re-renders
const RowRenderer = React.useCallback(({index, style}) => {
        const row = rows[index];
        prepareRow(row);
        return (
          // note the addition of style as an argument to getRowProps
          <tr {...row.getRowProps(style)}>
            {row.cells.map((cell) => {
              return (
                <td {...cell.getCellProps()}> {cell.render("Cell")}</td>
              );
            })}
          </tr>
        );
  // the useCallback dependency list
  },[prepareRow, rows]);
```

Which you would pass into the `FixedSizeList` like so:

```
  <FixedSizeList
        height={400}
        itemCount={10} //test before was {rows.length}
        itemSize={35}
        width={totalColumnsWidth}
      >
        {RowRenderer}
   </FixedSizeList>
```

Second, it is my understanding that basic table elements(`tr`, `th`, `td`, etc) do not work with the way positioning is handled in **react-window**. In the demo you linked above you will see that the windowing demo (unlike all of the other demos) uses `divs`. So your markup would now look like:

```
// add useCallback here to prevent unnecessary re-renders
const RowRenderer = React.useCallback(({index, style}) => {
        const row = rows[index];
        prepareRow(row);
        return (
          // note the addition of style as an argument to getRowProps
          <div {...row.getRowProps(style)}>
            {row.cells.map((cell) => {
              return (
                <div {...cell.getCellProps()}> {cell.render("Cell")}</div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
  // the useCallback dependency list
  },[prepareRow, rows]);
```

This works fine with **react-table** and I *think* you can set the `component` prop on each **Material-UI** table component. ie `<Table component='div'>...`, `<TableCell component='div'>...`, etc. That might start looking like:

```
   // add useCallback here to prevent unnecessary re-renders
    const RowRenderer = React.useCallback(({index, style}) => {
            const row = rows[index];
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              // note the addition of style as an argument to getRowProps
              <TableRow component='div' {...row.getRowProps(style)}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <TableCell  component='div' {...cell.getCellProps()}> {cell.render("Cell")}</TableCell>
                  );
                })}
              </TableRow>
            );
      // the useCallback dependency list
      },[prepareRow, rows]);
```

As far as bringing it all together with the EnhancedTable demo, it should be possible, if a little tricky. I'll leave that one for another answer.